# PHP - check multiple array key, if key has value

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array:

```
$my_array = array(1 => 'has value', 2 =>'', 3 => '');
```

I want to run a if statment to check if all key have value or not,
if there is not any value for all keys then return false

like:

```
if(any_key_has_value($my_array)){
    //run my query
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you define "has value" as "value `== true`":

```
if (count(array_filter($array)) == count($array)) {
    echo 'All elements have values';
}
```

Comment: Check with $settings=array('host'=>'localhost','user'=>true,'password'=>true,'database'=>true); and get true :P

Answer (score 1):

```
function hasValue($v) {
    return strval($v) != '';
}    
$res_array = array_filter($my_array, 'hasValue');
// any key has value
$any_key_has_value = 0 < sizeof($res_array);
// all keys have values
$all_keys_have_values = sizeof($my_array) == sizeof($res_array);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$my_array = array(1 => 'has value', 2 =>'', 3 => '');
```

simply try this

```
if (array_filter($my_array)) {
    // here  first value  `has value` 
}else{
 // all values are empty 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<?php
        $array = array('key1' => null, 'key2' => null, 'key3' => null, 'key4' => null);

        if (!array_filter($array)) {

            echo "All keys have null values";
        }
        else
        {
               // do something
        }
        ?>
```

-